# How grouping module in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, module

The structure of my android project:

> project-
>
> > |-moduleA
> >
> > |-moduleB
> >
> > |-moduleC
> >
> > |-moduleD

how to organize modules in groups like this:

> project-
>
> > |-group1
> >
> > > |-moduleA1
> > >
> > > |-moduleA2
> > >
> > > |-moduleA
> >
> > |-group2
> >
> > > |-moduleB1
> > >
> > > |-moduleB2
> > >
> > > |-moduleB3

move modules to directory， but compile error

any one can help me?  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as the above one, but I had to use a slightly different syntax

```
':group1:module1'
```

Gradle wouldn't accept the slash-notation.
(Sorry for the additional answer, I couldn't leave a comment)

Answer (score 4):

After moving modules to a group, clean your modules and re-build them.
[image]

Change **settings.gradle** from:

```
include ':app', ':module1', ':module2', ':module3'
```

to

```
include ':app', ':group1/module1', ':group1/module2', ':group1/module3'
```

Open **app/build.gradle** to edit dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    *
    *
    compile project(':group1/module1')
    compile project(':group1/module2')
    compile project(':group1/module3')
}
```

Now you can successfully build the project.